# how to change the color of existing text present in jpg image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

[image]I had tried using photoshop eye dropper tool and methods in GIMP but could not succeed.i have an jpeg image which has text in gray shade . i want  to change the gray shade colored text to red colored text . how to do it? in GIMP?

Comment: can you provide sample image on which you're trying if possible. the basic method to change text color might me very easy or hard depending on the image you trying to change so if possible provide us demo or sample image :)

Comment: how shall i attach the image ?

Comment: while asking or editing question there is photo frame icon on top bar .that's where you can upload image

Comment: i have attached the image .

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method using GIMP, in just 2 steps

1. Click *Colors > Levels* and create a levels adjustment like this, by clicking and dragging the little triangles in the input levels to the positions as shown. This will darken the text.

[image]

2. Click *Colors > Colorize*, choose a red colour, and move the Lightness slider until you get the result you want

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### With Gimp:

#### If you want to keep the washed out look:

1. Use the color picker to sample the color of the background
2. Add an alpha channel to the layer (allows it to be transparent) `Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel`
3. `Color>Color to alpha` and remove the background color. This will also make the characters partially transparent
4. Add a new layer, bucket fill with the color you sampled at step 1.
5. Drag that layer below the text layer (this should recreate the initial image)
6. Select the text layer in the Layers list
7. Set the alpha-lock on the layer (checkerboard icon at the top of the Layers list)
8. Bucket fill with color

[image]

#### For a more colorful look:

1. Use the color picker to sample the color of the background
2. Add an alpha channel to the layer (allows it to be transparent) `Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel`
3. Use the color selector to color-select the background
4. `Select>Grow` by 2px (the selection will cover the edges of the characters)
5. `Color>Color to alpha` and remove the background color.
6. `Select>None`
7. Add a new layer, bucket fill with the color you sampled at step 1.
8. Drag that layer below the text layer (this should recreate the initial image)
9. Select the text layer in the Layers list
10. Set the alpha-lock on the layer (checkerboard icon at the top of the Layers list)
11. Bucket fill with color

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Use `color overlay` with blending mode `overlay`**

Nothing to worry if you have basic knowledge of photoshop and if you have black and white layers :)

Just unlock layer if it locked-> double click on layer and select `Color Overlay` -> select red color and change `Blending Mode` to `Overlay` and that's It! followbelow image if you need detailed instruction :)

If you getting light results and if you want to darken it use adjustment layers like `Levels and Curves` etc.

[image]

Comment: how to do this in GIMP ?

Comment: don't you have photoshop ? if not then maybe billy kerr can help since he knows much about gimp

Comment: i dont have photoshop. i dont know billy kerr

Comment: Phoenix : thx for enhlightening me

Comment: just keep calm and soon you will get answer. many ppls uses gimp here just i don't XD

Comment: This can also be used with Gimp (`Overlay` or `Lighten only` modes) but both modes also put a tint on the background.